# Seaching using tags in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, tags

I am struggling to find a solution to this. I have tags that are inserted into the database in this form

mytags=`firsttag, secondtag, thirdtag`

On the single page I need to show related items based on these tags aso I am using

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tags LIKE \"%$mytags%\" ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5"
```

However this doesn't work much as it only searches for posts that have the exact same tagline (firsttag, secondtag, thirdtag) and not the posts that their tag contain one of the tags (firsttag, anothertag, andanothertag).

I thought of exploding mytags and then search using the first tag in the array, but this doesn't work very good.

Does anyone know an effective method of searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use separate table for post tags keeping? I mean for example table 'posts', table 'tags' and relation table 'posts_tags'.
Here is structure of 'posts':

```
id
title
content
```

Here is structure of 'tags':

```
id
tag_name
```

And here is structure if 'posts_tags':

```
id
post_id
tag_id
```

This is scheme of 'many to many' relationship model. And you can now simply find tags or/and posts through JOIN operator.

Comment: The "id" attribute in "posts_tags" is not even necessary.

Comment: Yes but what if you want to delete one of the relationship rules?

Comment: Whats wrong with `DELETE ... WHERE post_id=... AND tag_id=...`?

Comment: Nothing. But delete by ID is more beautifull, logic and compact. Also ID's can be indexed if you need it.

Comment: You can also index post_id and tag_id. And when talking about relations it makes more sense to talk about post_id=5 and tag_id=9 instead of ID=2 what does not relate to anything useful.

Comment: It structurize relations. Also I think that using one column for index is more optimized to index two columns anyway :) Also all relations may have their unique IDs to make simplify control over them.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a propper way to do it. Your database is not normalised. In short, it is impossible to do what you want, and even if it is, that'd be highly ineffective.

You have to create another table - **Tags**, and then another one to represent the connection of tags to Posts let's say **TagsPosts**, everything propperly indexed.

Comment: is possible:-) but not optimized

Comment: @ajreal, please post your solution, I guess it would make a nice difference from all the current answers.

Comment: use OR compare three tags..having count>=1

Comment: yes, and take care of all the exceptions, like abc matching abcd tag, whitespace, and dynamically generating mysql query. Unable to use any index, making thing slow as hell. :)

Comment: my purpose is to indicate the possible,not like what you said

Comment: @Rok SO [promotes politeness](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette) in communication, which includes comments. Please bear this in mind.

Comment: @JamWaffles, my response was to just as unpolite comment, which got deleted by the writer. I have now done the same.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) but also, I would highly recommend to normalize your database and use a proper structure.

Comment: Nice find! I didn't know that.

Comment: find_in_set() returns an integer no?

Comment: @Kbr89 Yes it does (or NULL).

Answer (score 0):

You should always [keep your data normalised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (one piece of data in each column). There's a solution to this problem using two tables; one for tags and one for posts and a MySQL [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php). Below is a very minimal example.

#### Table `posts`

```
id  int(11) Auto Increment   
title   char(255)
```

#### Table `tags`

```
id  int(11)  
postid  int(11)  
tag char(64)
```

#### Query to search for posts with tags containing `firstpost`

(important)

```
SELECT p.title FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN tags t
ON t.postid=p.id
WHERE t.tag LIKE '%firstpost%'
```

#### Sample data

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Post number 1'),
(2, 'Another post'),
(3, 'Third post');

INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `postid`, `tag`) VALUES
(0, 1,  'first_post'),
(0, 1,  'firstpost_secondtag'),
(0, 2,  'secondpost_firsttag');
```

As I said above, this is a very minimal example. The most important bit here is the use of `LEFT JOIN` and a separate tags table. It should be obvious to you that you simply replace `firstpost` in the `LIKE` statement with a PHP variable.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, but I want to keep my program simple. Seems like I don't have any choice. Thanks

Comment: My question looks rather long, but this is a simple as it gets; the `tags` table only needs two fields at minimum; tag text and the post ID that uses that tag. Your `posts` table doesn't need changing; only the `SELECT` query, which is pretty short. You can expand this example to use an intermediate table so you have a list of tags, and a sort of "interface" between posts and this tag list.